# p tag occupying 100% of size

Tags: html, css

In my project I have a problem. In the last area of the site I have a text written "Example" and an image on the side, but for some reason the image is below the text. I wanted to do the same thing as the top div, but invert the text on the left and the image on the right, does anyone know how I put the text up?

Code:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Manjari&display=swap');
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    outline: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
html, body, #root, .render{
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    background: #111;
    font-family: 'Manjari', sans-serif;
}
.mainBanner {
    background: url('https://i.ibb.co/7XY9yyb/fundo.jpg');
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
.variacao {
    height: 12%;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, transparent 0%, #111 100%);
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
.wall {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    width: 100%;
}
.topContainer {
    margin-top: 15px;
}
.topContainer h1 {
    font-size: 35px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #e50914;
}
.wellcomemsg {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 8%;
    font-size: 5vw;
    text-shadow: 1px 2px 3px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
    color: #FFF;
}
.btns button {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 15px 20px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 3px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #e50914;
    background: #e50914;
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 22px;
}
.multi {
    position: relative;
}
.multi p {
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 2vw;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 70px;
    margin-top: 12%;
}
.multi img {
    margin-bottom: 5%;
    opacity: 0.95;
    margin-left: 60px;
    width: 30%;
    margin-top: 4%;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.multi img:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}
.down {
    position: relative;
}
.down p {
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 2vw;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    margin-left: 70px;
    margin-top: 12%;
}
.down img {
    margin-bottom: 5%;
    opacity: 0.95;
    margin-right: 60px;
    width: 30%;
    float: right;
    margin-top: 0%;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.down img:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}
hr {
    border-color: #ccc;
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .wellcomemsg {
        font-size: 30px;
        margin-top: 8vh;
    }
    .btns button {
        margin-top: 20px;
        font-size: 20px;
    }
    .multi img {
        margin-top: 30px;
        width: 90%;
        margin-left: 5%;
    }
    .multi p {
        width: 100%;
        margin-top: 8%;
        margin-right: 0;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 20px;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="render">
        <div class="mainBanner">
            <div class="wall">
                <div class="topContainer">
                    <h1>IMM | YouWatch</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="wellcomemsg">
                    <p>Bem-vindo a YouWatch</p>
                    <p>Cria uma conta gratis ou experimenta</p>
                    <p>Uma conta paga durante 1 Mês</p>
                    <div class="btns">
                        <button>Criar uma conta</button>
                        <button>Iniciar Sessão</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="variacao"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="multi">
        <img src="https://i.ibb.co/q9s3R9v/multi.png" alt="Multi Plataformas" title="Multi Plataformas"/>
        <p>Veja os seus filmes e series favoritos onde e quando quiser!</p>
        </div>
        <hr />
        <div class="down">
        <p>Example</p>
        <img src="https://i.ibb.co/q9s3R9v/multi.png" alt="Multi Plataformas" title="Multi Plataformas"/>
        </div>
        <hr />
        <p>T</p>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image is underneath the 'Example' line in your code, surely this is why?

```
<div class="down">
  <p>Example</p>
  <img src="https://i.ibb.co/q9s3R9v/multi.png" alt="Multi Plataformas" title="Multi Plataformas"/>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, the problem is this, I copied the structure of the top div, changed the css and forgot to change the position. Within 5 minutes already accepted the answer

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below css:

```
.down p {
 display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, also the sum of the above resolution with yours solved my problem, thanks! Sorry but I can only accept one answer